# Can't get three result on array of length three with three conditions

Tags: javascript, node.js, logic

I having problem with my loop in which I have an array whoose length is three and I want to check three conditions on that array and only want three result not more than three.

```js
var myArray = ['x','q','z'] // or array may also be myArray = ['p','z','y'] or ['q', 'x'] or something like this
   for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
      if (myArray[i] == 'x') {
  console.log('x')
      } else {
   console.log('a')
      } 
      
      if (myArray[i] == 'y') {
  console.log('y')
      } else {
  console.log('b')
      } 

      if (myArray[i] == 'z') {
  console.log('z')
      } else {
  console.log('c')
      }
   }
```

Result is:

```
x
b
c
a
b
c
a
b
z
```

But the result which I want is

```
x
b
z
```

How, I can improve my logic to get my expected result, that is only three results for checking array of length three with three different conditions.

**I have to get exactly three result for given three conditions no matter what is array length.**

Comment: Sorry, you cannot achieve the result you want with the logic you have. You'll need to be more specific in how you want to reconcile what happens when more than one of the conditions evaluates to false.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is, that after each if statement you have else. That means, on each iteration you always will have 3 outputs. You need just if, or if and else if. Also use continue or return, to go to next iteration on success.

Comment: Yes, but that will also not give me, my expected result if array is of length two like myArray = ['a','z'] then what?

Comment: To make things clearly, use Objects, not Strings. Than you can specify property and use it like marker to know which conditions you should use.

Comment: @SyedMuhammadAsad What is the expected result for an array of length 2?

Comment: @Barmar for array (q, x) result should be x, b, c.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in the above answers, for each iteration of the `for` loop there are 3 pairs of conditionals printing 3 values. Therefore, we need a mechanism to `continue` the loop to the next iteration if we've matched the winner or it's corresponding fallback value (in else statements). Here is what I can come up with:

```js
var myArray = ['q', 'x', 'z']
var ifArray = ['x', 'y', 'z'];
var elseArray = ['a', 'b', 'c']

function test(jackpot, fallback) {
  for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
    if (myArray[i] == jackpot) {
      return jackpot;
    }
  }
  return fallback;
}

for (var i = 0; i < ifArray.length; i++) {
  var result = test(ifArray[i], elseArray[i]);
  console.log(result);
}
```

`myArray` is obviously `myArray`, `ifArray` contains the values of the `if` statements and `elseArray` contains the values of the `else` statements from the question.

Answer (score -1):

Your issue is that each time your loop runs it checks each array item with the three different if-else statements.  Basically its checking if each item is 'x' or not, if each item is 'y' or not, and if each item is 'z' or not. This is why your output has much more letters than expected.

A better way would be to first check the iteration of the loop and then do your if-else statements based on that.

```
var myArray = ['x', 'q', 'z']
for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
  // Only checks during first iteration (When myArray[i] == 'x')
  if (i === 0) {
    if (myArray[i] == 'x') {
    console.log('x')
    } else {
    console.log('a')
    }
  // Only checks during second iteration (When myArray[i] == 'q')
  } else if (i == 1) {
    if (myArray[i] == 'y') {
    console.log('y')
    } else {
    console.log('b')
    }
  // Only checks during third iteration (When myArray[i] == 'z')
  } else if (i == 2) {
    if (myArray[i] == 'z') {
    console.log('z')
    } else {
    console.log('c')
    }
  }
}
// Result: 
//x
//b
//z
```

Comment: I have explained above myArray, it can be [p, z, y], then in this case result will be a, b, c but the result should be a, y, z.